# ansible docker mount multiple port

Tags: docker, ansible

ansible version

```
ansible --version
ansible 2.5.5
```

docker version

```
docker --version
Docker version 18.03.1-ce, build 9ee9f40
```

my Examples

```
- name: start container
  docker_container:
    name: "tomcat-container"
    image: "tomcat-images"
    state: started
    ports:
      - "{{ item[0]}}:{{ item[1] }}"
    with_nested:
      - [8080,8080]
      - [8081,8081]
```

FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'item' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/home/playbook/roles/ts-docker/tasks/main.yml': line 81, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: start container\n  ^ here\n"}

...'item' is undefined

How to solve the problem of mounting multiple port?

-_-||  English is not good, forgive me

Answer (score 1):

You just need to reduce the indent of the with_nested line like this:

```
- name: start container
  docker_container:
    name: "tomcat-container"
    image: "tomcat-images"
    state: started
    ports:
      - "{{ item[0]}}:{{ item[1] }}"
  with_nested:
    - [8080,8080]
    - [8081,8081]
```

with_nested is an option for the task and the way you had it indented it was an option for the module (docker_container).